# raspian wifi: will it switch over ho higher priority wifi when detected?

Tags: wifi

Say I've got this wifi config:

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
network={
    ssid="wifi_A"
    psk="passwordOfA"
    priority=1
}
network={
   ssid="wifi_B"
   psk="passwordOfB"
   priority=2
}
```

Now, say that this happens:

- A is down when booting, so we connect to B
- ... some time passes ...
- A comes back up

Will raspian switch over to wifi A, or will it stay on wifi B?

And if the default behaviour is to stay on B, how can I make it so that I automatically switch over to A when it gets availible?

Comment: Do you have different sessions (e.g. youtube streaming, ssh sessions etc.) running on each connection, so it doesn't matter that one connection disconnected and its sessions break? Or do you want to have the same sessions on both connections and want to switch them on the fly without breaking the sessions? Then both connections must provide exactly the same services.

Comment: your question is a Linux question, not an RPi question

Comment: @Ingo It's running as a server and I have the IP forwarding only on one wifi. So it doesn't matter if connections break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once connected to a network it will remain unless the network is shut down.

This is normal behaviour for all computers.

If you restart networking it MAY change, but even this can not be guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: @rutchkiwi It should be possible with bonding but haven't tested it.